# Add Folder named like project to build path

Tags: f#, f#-fake

I have made the example build script, but since i have several projects in my solution i need them built into different folders.

Main question would be how to get the name of the current file processed so i can add it to the buildDir string.

```
Target "BuildApp" (fun _->
!! "**/*.csproj"
  -- "*Test*/*.csproj"
  -- "**/*Test*.csproj"
  -- "**/TextControlEditorLight.csproj"
  |> MSBuildRelease buildDir "Build"
  |> Log "AppBuild-Output: "
```

I need something like (buildDir + "/" + projectName), i searched already the web but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be an easier way to do this (I'm not familiar with *all* the FAKE libraries), but one way to do this is to explicitly iterate over the project files and build then one by one.

The `!!` operator returns a sequence of matching files. In your version, you just pass them to `MSBuildRelease`, but you can also iterate over them using `Seq.iter`:

```
Target "BuildApp" (fun _->
  !! "**/*.csproj"
    -- "*Test*/*.csproj"
    -- "**/*Test*.csproj"
    -- "**/TextControlEditorLight.csproj"
  |> Seq.iter (fun project ->
    // This function will be called for individual project files and so
    // we can do whatever we want here. Like build a single project and
    // specify output directory based on the project file name.
    [project]
    |> MSBuildRelease (buildDir @@ Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(project)) "Build"
    |> Log "AppBuild-Output: ")
)
```